# What does the $\leq_{\mathrm{P}}$ symbol mean?

Tags: complexity-theory, notation

What does $\leq_{\mathrm{P}}$ mean? Is it supposed to mean less than or equal polynomial time?

Answer (score 7):

It should have been defined wherever you've seen it used. It normally stands for [polynomial-time reducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction) of one kind or another; usually many-one reducibility.

Comment: I am using it to show that Directed Hamilton Cycle  ≤P Undirected Hamilton Cycle.

Comment: Yep. So it's whatever version of polynomial-time reducibility you're using in your course. You need to check the definition given by your lecturer.